# Replace multiple backslashes with HTML entities in Java string for JSP generated Json

Tags: java, json, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

after hours of googeling and searching within SO, I finaly come to the place where I need to ask you! :)

Situation is the following:
A webservice delivers data in a CDATA. This data is parsed and put into our model. Using Spring MVC we access the model inside the JSP files to create....here come the point... JSON! Don't ask, historically! ;-)

Now, somehow someone came to the glorious idea to put multiple (back)slashes into a title property. The getTitle() method returns the string "/// Glasvegas \\". This of course doesn't work, if we do a JavaSCript eval() on the JSON (created within the JSP) to get the JavaScript Json object. It simply interprets the backslashes as comment, making the Json invalid.
I tried to use the escapeHtml() methods from apache.common and springframework, but they both just ignore the backslashes while encoding all other special chars correctly.

Then I tried to write my own method:

```
public static String escapeHTML(String string) {         
    String foreslash="&#92;";
    String regex="\\\\";
    System.out.println(string.replaceAll(regex,foreslash));
    string.replaceAll(regex,foreslash);
    return string;
}
```

In console output the string is correctly replaced, but if break at the return and inspect the variable 'string' in the debugger it's still "/// Glasvegas \\". Also the same in the generated JSP.

So, I'm kind of lost here.

Regards,
ASP

Comment: String is immutable. try string=string.replaceAll(regex,foreslash);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strings are immutable. the name of the method "replaceAll" makes it sound as though you're actually modifying the string object itself, but you're not. the method just returns the result of the operation. this is why you get the correct output from the System.out.println. but then you make an error of thought, thinking that just because the call is standing by itself, not inside a System.out.println, the java code should understand by itself that this time you want the change to be permanent in the string object ;)

try to rewrite the end of your method like this:

```
System.out.println(string.replaceAll(regex,foreslash));
return string.replaceAll(regex,foreslash);
```

also, the virable name "foreslash" makes it sound as though 92 is the code for a forward slash. maybe it is, i don't know. your regular expression then looks for a backslash. that's a bit confusing!

Comment: OMG, thank you for even answering this question. You're right! This is so embarrassing! Loosing the sight of the wood for the tree. :-)